# iTunes could not back up the iPhone because the backup could not be saved on the computer

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I keep getting the message “iTunes could not backup the iPhone because the backup could not be saved on the computer”.  I upgraded my computer, so it’s all brand new, huge hard disc. It runs Win 7 and has a brand new install of iTunes 11.1.4.62. I’m using an administrator account.

I can’t get any backup to work. Not from my iPhone 5S, not from my wife’s iPhone 4S nor from her iPad. The 4S did backup once or twice before I got the 5S. Since I reset it for my wife, nothing. The 5S is running iOS 7, the 4S iOS 6. I have googled it for a solution and tried deleting the backup directory and uninstalled and reinstalled iTunes, no success. I Can't find anything else useful.

I get some backup files created in the Backup directory. It creates the long alphameric directory name and under it one called `Snapshot`. This directory contains many files with long alphameric names and a file called `Status.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with my 4S, and it was fine before.  Found the solution here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2529?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Basically had to copy my last backup to my homepage (drag/drop), delete the old backups (drag to trash), and then Sync and backup worked fine in iTunes.